# Run example code in a Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup

I'm brand new to Java and have managed to write a "hello world" project in Eclipse. The next step I'd like to do is to run some example code in an Repository, JSoup, I'm interested in using.

For example, I'd like to run [JSoup's "list links" example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links).

I download the JSoup repo into my workspace directory and imported the Jsoup project, but when I go to run "list links" example it says "selection can't be run". How do specifically run the "list links" example?

Comment: Find the class which contains `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: what ide are you using ? The ListLinks class has the main..

Comment: Open the file that contains the main method(ListLinks class), right click in that window and select "Run As" > Java Application

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. @MattBall yes the ListLinks class has the main.  --Susie, It's not giving me the option of running as a Java application.

Comment: If you want to use library code, I'd suggest you use a build tool that does dependency management for you. I think Maven is the most widely used. Simply create a new Maven project and add Jsoup to your dependencies (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.8.1) and you can use it just like the Java standard library.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start from scratch.

1. Create a new "Java Project"
2. create a file called "ListLinks"
3. Run the application as "Java application"

1  File > New > Java Project (If you don't see Java Project, click "Other" and you should be able to find it there. )

2  Name the project "Test" and finish the process

3  Create a file in "default package" called ListLinks. You will find this "default package" folder inside "src" folder in your "Test" project

Right click on "default package" > new > class (Name it ListLinks)
       Make sure to check the `public static void main(String[] args)` check box under `Which  method stubs would you like to create?`

4  click Finish

5  Open the file you just created and paste this line

```
System.out.println("I am running my application");
```

This is what your file should look like now:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("I am running my application");
    }

}
```

6  Now right click anywhere in that file > "Run As" > "Java Application"

You should see the following printed in your console:

```
I am running my application
```

Once you see you application running, you can then copy paste your code from JSoup's example.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem, too. Here is a blank template project you might find useful - https://github.com/jadekler/git-java-empty. It's basically a super simple gradle+one file+one unit test. Hope this helps!